How to handle AVI XVID Packed Bitstream in Mediacodec
I am working on fix for VLC Android issue
In VLC Android (HW acceleration on) and in native android video player playback of videos with xvid packed bitstream is jerky. In VLC when hw acceleration off video plays smoothly so it's most likely issue with Mediacodec.
So how can i handle xvid with pb in Mediacodec side?
One possible fix for this is force to hw acceleration off for packed bitstream.
Is there any way to use mediacodec for PB? Like unpacking frame before sending to mediacodec for decoding.
